# Exception in lazy loading (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, exception, orm, lazy-loading, dispose

I use *Entity Framework* in my project. The issue is well known but supposed solutions (eg. [this](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/01/08/entity-framework-first-steps/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360372/the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used-for-opera)) doesn't work for me.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns complete list of lecturers from DB.
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<Lecturer> GetAllLecturers()
{
    IList<Lecturer> query;
    using (var dbb = new AcademicTimetableDbContext())
    {
        query = (from b in dbb.Lecturers select b).ToList();
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(query[0].AcademicDegree); // Exception (***)
    return query;
}
```

Exception (***):

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

```cs
public class Lecturer
{
    public Lecturer()
    {
        this.Timetables = new List<Timetable>();
        this.Courses = new List<Course>();
    }

    public int Id_Lecturer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Phone_Number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Academic_Degree_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AcademicDegree AcademicDegree { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Timetable> Timetables { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lazy loading works until your `DbContext` lives.

With the `using` you dispose your `DbContext` so EF will throw an exception when you try to access the navigation properties outside the `using` block.

You can test this with moving the `Debug.WriteLine` inside the `using` block where it won't throw exception:

```
using (var dbb = new AcademicTimetableDbContext())
{
    query = (from b in dbb.Lecturers select b).ToList();
    Debug.WriteLine(query[0].AcademicDegree);
}
```

And the solution is to tell EF to [eagerly load the navigation properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232) with the using `Include` method:

```
using (var dbb = new AcademicTimetableDbContext())
{
    query = (from b in dbb.Lecturers.Include(l => l.AcademicDegree) select b)
      .ToList();

}
Debug.WriteLine(query[0].AcademicDegree);
```

Comment: @patryk.beza you can have multiple includes: `dbb.Lecturers.Include(l => l.AcademicDegree).Include(l => l.Timetables).Include(l => l.Courses )` I know it is not so nice but this is how EF works.