# Lazy Loading with Partial Views - ObjectContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360372/the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used-for-opera) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398356/how-to-solve-the-error-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-l) and others like them but I am still getting

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult Home()
{
    HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
    return View(model);

}
```

Here's the HomeViewModel object:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> Menu { get; set; }

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        using (Core db = new Core())
        {
            Menu = db.Menu.ToList();
            Dashboard = db.Dashboard.ToList<DashboardItem>();

            foreach (MenuItem item in Menu)
            {
                item.Items = (from mi in db.Menu where mi.Parent.MenuItemID == item.MenuItemID select mi).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Home view:

```
@model AVP.DAL.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">@Html.Partial("SidebarP", Model)</div>

    <div class="col-lg-8">@Html.Partial("DashboardP", Model)</div>
</div>
```

And here's the SidebarP partial view:

```
@model AVP.DAL.HomeViewModel

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-stacked">
        @foreach (AVP.DAL.MenuItem mi in Model.Menu.Where(m => m.Menu.Name == "SideBar")) // <-- exception thrown here
        {
            // whatever
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

The exception is thrown at the foreach but as the link questions suggested, I have called ToList() to force the db access.

I took out the `using()` around the `DbContext` and that fixed the problem but I don't understand why that should matter when I have brought the data into the model?

Am I putting the application at risk of a memory leak by leaving that using out?

Thanks for any help,

.pd.

Comment: The way lazy loading works is that until the foreach is called you've not round tripped to the database. Which means that the context is already disposed.

Comment: You might want to rethink your design, take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: If you project your query into a flattened model you would avoid this problem.  Search for 'LINQ projection'

Comment: www.blackwasp.co.uk has great explanations of LINQ projection and a load of other stuff too if anybody's looking.

And that tutorial showing the repository pattern was great.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding .ToList() on the line you are getting the error on?